# Showing detailed Database Informations on Click

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, bootstrap-4

I want to show a list of Data from a Database (only the important parts) but want to show ALL data of said ID after a button click.

Any idea how I do it the best?

Also is there a way to "Live update" a table without refreshing the whole page every X seconds? Because while reading the extended data wouldn't it also vanish on reload? (I'm rather new in PHP)

Current Code for my Table (+ old code with full data which should be shown on press for the specific fieldID)

new operator.php (with less data)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['loginerror'])) {
    $loginerror=$_GET['loginerror'];
}
 if(!empty($loginerror)){  echo '<p class="errmsg">LOGIN FAILED TRY AGAIN</p>'; } ?>
  <div>
  <center>
<?php echo $deleteMsg??''; ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="GeneratedTable" style="font-size: small; text-align: center;">
       <thead><tr class=tablehead>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 90px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">FieldID</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 90px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Username</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 300px; text-align: center;">Field SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 40px; font-size: small; max-height: 300px; text-align: center;">EVR</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <?php
      if(is_array($fetchData)){      
      $sn=1;
      foreach($fetchData as $data){
    ?>
      <tr style="background: url(images/<?php echo $data['EVR']??''; ?>.png)">
      <td><?php echo $data['FieldID']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Username']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['FieldS']??''; ?></td>
      <td><img width="50%" height="50%" src="./images/<?php echo $data['EVR']??''; ?>o.png"></img></td> 
     </tr>
     <?php
      $sn++;}}else{ ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
    <?php echo $fetchData; ?>
  </td>
    <tr>
    <?php
    }?>
    </tbody>
     </table>
```

old operator.php (with all data which i want to show after clicking on the FieldID or a button etc)

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['loginerror'])) {
    $loginerror=$_GET['loginerror'];
}
 if(!empty($loginerror)){  echo '<p class="errmsg">LOGIN FAILED TRY AGAIN</p>'; } ?>
  <div>
  <center>
<?php echo $deleteMsg??''; ?>
    <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="GeneratedTable" style="font-size: small; text-align: center;">
       <thead><tr class=tablehead>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 90px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">FieldID</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 90px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">Username</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#1 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#2 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#3 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#4 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#5 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#6 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#7 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#8 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#9 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">#10 Mass</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">%</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 30px; font-size: small; max-height: 30px; text-align: center;">SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 60px; font-size: small; max-height: 300px; text-align: center;">Field SCU</th>
         <th class="block" style="min-width: 40px; font-size: small; max-height: 300px; text-align: center;">EVR</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
  <?php
      if(is_array($fetchData)){      
      $sn=1;
      foreach($fetchData as $data){
    ?>
      <tr style="background: url(images/<?php echo $data['EVR']??''; ?>.png)">
      <td><?php echo $data['FieldID']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Username']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock1m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock1p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock1s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock2m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock2p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock2s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock3m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock3p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock3s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock4m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock4p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock4s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock5m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock5p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock5s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock6m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock6p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock6s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock7m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock7p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock7s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock8m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock8p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock8s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock9m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock9p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock9s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock10m']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock10p']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['Rock10s']??''; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $data['FieldS']??''; ?></td>
      <td><img width="50%" height="50%" src="./images/<?php echo $data['EVR']??''; ?>o.png"></img></td> 
     </tr>
     <?php
      $sn++;}}else{ ?>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="8">
    <?php echo $fetchData; ?>
  </td>
    <tr>
    <?php
    }?>
    </tbody>
     </table>
```

Every help and nudge in the right direction is welcome :) thanks in advance

ps. Yes I know I used a lot of inline styling I'm transferring it later to the CSS I was just messing around quickly with the sizes.

Comment: Your question isn't very specific. Please see [ask].

Comment: You'll find that "messing around with styles" tends to create big messes that you have to clean up anyway. Just don't. Use classes or simple element selectors.

Comment: `is there a way to "Live update" a table without refreshing the whole page every X seconds`...yes, you can use AJAX or websockets or server-sent events